# Как удалить из значения в колонке подстроку взятую из другой таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `catalog_items` в ней есть колонка `caption`, есть вторая таблица `brands` в которой есть колонка с именем бренда. Мне нужно из колонки `caption` убрать название бренда, которое нужно взять в таблице `brand`. Убрать нужно без учёта регистра.

У меня пока что вышло так

```
SELECT id, REPLACE (caption, CONCAT(upper(left(brand.alias,1)),
              substr(brand.alias,2)), "TEST")
FROM catalog_items_content, (SELECT alias FROM brand WHERE 1) AS brand
WHERE caption RLIKE brand.alias
ORDER BY id asc;
```

Как мне сделать update в таблице по значениях этого запроса?

Comment: Хорошо бы видеть таблицу. Не понятно что за подстрока и т.п.

Comment: Єсть таблица catalog_items в ней есть колонка caption.
Єсть вторая таблица brands в которой есть колона с именем бренда. Мне нужно из колонки caption убрать название бренда которое сеть в таблице brand. без учота регистра.

Comment: У меня пока что вышло так, но как мне сделать упдайт в таблице по значениях этого запроса
'
SELECT id, REPLACE (`caption`, CONCAT(upper(left(brand.alias,1)),substr(brand.alias,2)) , "TEST")
FROM `catalog_items_content`, (SELECT `alias` FROM `brand` WHERE 1) AS brand 
WHERE `caption` RLIKE brand.alias 
ORDER BY `id` asc;

Comment: Так что сделать нужно? Update или Delete?